# An unhandled Exception of type 'System-stack overflow Exception' occured in mscorlib.dll

Tags: sql, winforms, recursion, c#-3.0

```
class BaseData
{
    public string DbConnection = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["OLTPPOINTER_Connectionstring"].ConnectionString;
    public string DbConnection_Report = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["OLTPPOINTER_Connectionstring"].ConnectionString;

    protected SqlConnection OpenConnection()
    {
        **SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(DbConnection);**----"StackOverflow Exception was unhandled"

        try
        {
            if (conn.State != ConnectionState.Open)
            {
                conn.Open();
            }

            return conn;
        }
        catch { throw; }
    }
```

I used recursion,It works sometime without Exception.
In some cases it throws an Exception:-

```
   SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(DbConnection); 
                    or
   SqlDataAdapter adpt = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
   adpt.Fill(ds, "DataSet");
   CloseConnection(cmd.Connection);
```

does recursive call makes the throw an Exception.How to handle it

Answer (score 0):

Yes, recursion implies nested method calls. Too many nested method calls will indeed throw a `StackOverflow`. And you should avoid to open multiple connections recursively.

Comment: Avoid Multiple connections mean-should i open sql connection onces and use through the operation without closing the connection

Comment: Well it depends on what exactly you're doing in that recursive portion. This is your call to choose if it's better to hog a connection for the time being of all your recursive calls, or to open/close the connection within each recursive call.

Comment: Code is now working without Exception.....I have put thread.sleep(3000) after each time,I call the recursive function.